# assign variables with LESS css using mixins

Tags: less

Is it possible to assign a variable based on another variable using ***less*** css?

pseudo code:

```
@userpick = red; /* this changes based on user pick */

@color1 = red;
@color2 = blue;

if( @userpick == @color1)
  @systempick = @color2
else( @userpick == @color2)
  @systempick = @color1
```

I want to be able to use `@systempick` as a color value not as a css style. For example:

```
border: 5px dashed @systempick;
```

Answer (score 4):

### Doesn't use a mixin, but resolves your desire

If the `@userpick` is stored as a string instead, then that could be used to access another variable name based off of it (a variable variable), like so:

**LESS**

```css
@userpick: "blue"; /* this changes based on user pick, saved as a string */
@setopposite: "@{userpick}-opp";

//set opposing values
@red-opp: blue;
@blue-opp: red;

@systempick: @@setopposite;

.test {
  color: @systempick;
}
```

**CSS Output** (note how `blue` outputs `#ff0000`, i.e. `red`)

```
/* this changes based on user pick */
.test {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

Since you are dealing with colors, the `@userpick` needs to be saved as a string because otherwise, LESS will automatically assign it a hex value rather than the color name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use guards in mixins to change the color that is used, e.g.

```
.a when (@userpick = @color1) {
  color: @color2;
}

.a when (@userpick = @color2) {
  color: @color1;
}
```

You might get code duplication but its the only way to get an if statement.

Other ways are possible (e.g. inline javascript if using less.js or a function plugin if using dotless) but are probably a little hacky.

Comment: The problem with using this solution is that the duplication may not be manageable when using many colors on different styles. I've posted an updated solution. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get what I needed, however this may not work on the PHP port of Less.
This was a bit tricky since you can assign variables only once. There are also some restrictions regarding scope of variables. I'm also comparing color values using HSV (hue, saturation, value)

```
.set_colors(#F00, #00F, #F00); /* pass red, blue and user pick */

.set_colors(@c1, @c2, @u) when (hue(@c1) = hue(@u)) and  (saturation(@c1) = saturation(@u)) and  (lightness(@c1) = lightness(@u)){
    @color1 = @c1;
    @color2 = @c2;
    @userpick = @c1;
    @systempick = @c2;
} 
.set_colors(@c1, @c2, @u) when (hue(@c2) = hue(@u)) and  (saturation(@c2) = saturation(@u)) and  (lightness(@c2) = lightness(@u)){
    @color1 = @c1;
    @color2 = @c2;
    @userpick = @c2;
    @systempick = @c1;
}
```